# Is it possible to distinguish lanes in a route?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I trace a route through GMaps V3 and the `DirectionsService`.

This is the code :

```
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({ 
    strokeColor: '#94c970', 
    strokeWeight: 7 
});

directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ polylineOptions: polyline, suppressMarkers: true });

var request = {
    origin: puntoPartenza,
    destination: puntoArrivo,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
});
```

it is a freeway, having 2 lanes, and I'd like to distinguish it on the map. Is it possible?

Need I third part plugins?

**Edit** : dunno if you understand what I mean with lanes :) I mean : the one with 2-3 traffic lane.

Comment: I understand "lanes", but I don't understand "dunno". :-)

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dunno :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that information is not available from the Google Maps API v3 or from any third party services that I have heard of.

Answer (score 2):

OpenStreetMap provides information on the number of lanes, which may be helpful depending on what you're using it for.
Kind of late I realize...

Here is an example that shows the number of lanes on a stretch of road:
http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/91741086

They have an API you could use to query this data. You may be able to combine it with your Google Maps API calls to do what you want.

FYI you may want to research OpenStreetMap first. They're a well known provider but I don't know how accurate their data is.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As Larry, (geocodezip), said, the routing engine does not provide that information.
However, depending on what you want to use it for, there might be some creative ways of figuring out how wide the road is, for example, if you get directions from A to B and then from B to A, you can calculate how far apart the two polylines are and work out, (approximately), how wide the road is based on that.

**Edit - Additional note:**

> If you are trying to find out how to do something, begin by describing
>   the goal. Only then describe the particular step towards it that you
>   are blocked on.

From: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal